# Galaxy S3 running CM11 - SystemUpdateService keeps getting disabled

Tags: google-play-services, services

SystemUpdateService is currently destroying my battery (phone awake 98% of the time) because it's *not* running ([*The update services acquires a wakelock to check for updates, but since SystemUpdateService is disabled, it never finishes the check and the device stays awake.*](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/04/16/google-play-services-causing-severe-wakelock-issues-on-cyanogen-os-12-and-cm12-patch-coming-next-week/))

The service is under both of the following apps:

- Google Play Services
- Google Play Services Framework

If I use the [DisableService](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice&hl=en_GB) app I can kick them back into action again... but whenever I restart my phone, they're disabled again. Also, sometimes they randomly switch off again at random.

Any idea how to keep these services running please?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have the app ops option under settings ? if not are you open to install it from play store ?

Comment: add more info about your problem, so you want those two google play services running all the time or you don't want them running all the time? (because you said 'Any idea how to keep these services running please?'). Please ask clearly once again.

Comment: Thanks @ranjithstar256 - I've just updated the original post with more context :)

Comment: Thanks @lord-ralf-adolf - I think I've used this app before, but I've just installed it and will give it another go.

Comment: I don't think your problem is that the services not running ,it's a known bug that have been reported on XDA several time and I had and still have it I fixed it by denying wake lock permissions from the google play services (not relly a fix but a work arround) you can try that and tell me if your device is sleeping fine or not

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I think you could also mention the tool or the tutorial in a comment that you used to deny that wake lock permission (like Amplify or something), and if it works for OP, then it would be worth having it as an answer.

Comment: The tool I used is app ops ,I disabled the the following permissions to the Google play services : keep awake ,wake up and auto start